# How to display Sale label on configurable product

Tags: magento2

I am not able to display `SALE` labels on configurable products.

I am able to display `NEW` when I set a product as new for a certain period of time, however when I have a special price on a product I am not able to display the `SALE` label.

I am using Magento 2.3.2. Is there anything I can do? I saw that there is this issue already reported here [Magento 2 configurable products issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14278) but as I understood I should not be able to set a product as `NEW` as well.

Hopefully, someone can assist with this further.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a `<div>` with your `SALE` label on the product list page where you want to display the `SALE` label. For e.g.

```
<div class="sale_label" style="display: none;">//your sale label</div>
```

Now on the same file check if the current product is configurable product than check if its child products have a special price or not.

```
$configProduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

$_children = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($configProduct);
$salePrice = array();
foreach ($_children as $child){
    $salePrice[] = $child->getSpecialPrice();
}
if($salePrice != ''){ ?>
<script>
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
   jQuery(document).ready( function() {
     jQuery("sale_label").show();
   });
});
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

You can use it without Object Manager.

Comment: This has probably a huge performance impact, if you load each product in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Our solution for a customer was, to create a new attribute `is_on_sale` which is updated each time a configurable or it's simples are changed.

Then we simply use that attribute to display a sale label and also can filter by this attribute.

Not a super sophisticated solution, but it works.

Other solutions have the problem that you either need to load all simples in the product-list-loop which has a big performance impact or mess around with the indexers.